# How to validate login and registration form in angular 8

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, angular8

I tried to implement login and registration form in my application everything is working fine but except backend validation. Backend validation not working like error message "User already exists" and "User does not exists". I do not know how to implement it. If anyone know please help.

I got script from here for login and registration:
https://github.com/ArjunAranetaCodes/MoreCodes-Youtube/tree/master/mean-mongodb-login-reg

routes/Users.js:

```
    const express = require('express')
const users = express.Router()
const cors = require('cors')
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')

const User = require('../models/User')
users.use(cors())

process.env.SECRET_KEY = 'secret'

users.post('/register', (req, res) => {
  const today = new Date()
  const userData = {
    first_name: req.body.first_name,
    last_name: req.body.last_name,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
    created: today
  }

  User.findOne({
    email: req.body.email
  })
    //TODO bcrypt
    .then(user => {
      if (!user) {
        User.create(userData)
          .then(user => {
            const payload = {
              _id: user._id,
              first_name: user.first_name,
              last_name: user.last_name,
              email: user.email
            }
            let token = jwt.sign(payload, process.env.SECRET_KEY, {
              expiresIn: 1440
            })
            res.json({ token: token })
          })
          .catch(err => {
            res.send('error: ' + err)
          })
      } else {
        res.json({ error: 'User already exists' })
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.send('error: ' + err)
    })
})

users.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  User.findOne({
    email: req.body.email
  })
    .then(user => {
      if (user) {
        const payload = {
          _id: user._id,
          first_name: user.first_name,
          last_name: user.last_name,
          email: user.email
        }
        let token = jwt.sign(payload, process.env.SECRET_KEY, {
          expiresIn: 1440
        })
        res.json({ token: token })
      } else {
        res.json({ error: 'User does not exist' })
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.send('error: ' + err)
    })
})

users.get('/profile', (req, res) => {
  var decoded = jwt.verify(req.headers['authorization'], process.env.SECRET_KEY)

  User.findOne({
    _id: decoded._id
  })
    .then(user => {
      if (user) {
        res.json(user)
      } else {
        res.send('User does not exist')
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.send('error: ' + err)
    })
})

module.exports = users
```

register.component.html:

```
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 mt-5 mx-auto">
      <form (submit)="register()">
        <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Register</h1>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">First name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" placeholder="Enter your first name" [(ngModel)]="credentials.first_name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Last name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name" placeholder="Enter your lastname name" [(ngModel)]="credentials.last_name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="email">Email address</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Enter email" [(ngModel)]="credentials.email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="password">Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" [(ngModel)]="credentials.password">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Register!</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

register.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'
import { AuthenticationService, TokenPayload } from '../authentication.service'
import { Router } from '@angular/router'

@Component({
  templateUrl: './register.component.html'
})
export class RegisterComponent {
  credentials: TokenPayload = {
    _id: '',
    first_name: '',
    last_name: '',
    email: '',
    password: ''
  }

  constructor(private auth: AuthenticationService, private router: Router) {}

  register() {
    this.auth.register(this.credentials).subscribe(
      () => {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/profile')
      },
      err => {
        console.error(err)
      }
    )
  }
}
```

login.component.html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 mt-5 mx-auto">
      <form (submit)="login()">
        <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Please sign in</h1>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="email">Email address</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Enter email" [(ngModel)]="credentials.email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="password">Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" [(ngModel)]="credentials.password">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Sign in</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

login.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'
import { AuthenticationService, TokenPayload } from '../authentication.service'
import { Router } from '@angular/router'

@Component({
  templateUrl: './login.component.html'
})
export class LoginComponent {
  credentials: TokenPayload = {
    _id: '',
    first_name: '',
    last_name: '',
    email: '',
    password: ''
  }

  constructor(private auth: AuthenticationService, private router: Router) {}

  login() {
    this.auth.login(this.credentials).subscribe(
      () => {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/profile')
      },
      err => {
        console.error(err)
      }
    )
  }
}
```

authentication.service.ts:

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs'
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'
import { Router } from '@angular/router'

export interface UserDetails {
  _id: string
  first_name: string
  last_name: string
  email: string
  password: string
  exp: number
  iat: number
}

interface TokenResponse {
  token: string
}

export interface TokenPayload {
  _id: string
  first_name: string
  last_name: string
  email: string
  password: string
}

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {
  private token: string

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {}

  private saveToken(token: string): void {
    localStorage.setItem('usertoken', token)
    this.token = token
  }

  private getToken(): string {
    if (!this.token) {
      this.token = localStorage.getItem('usertoken')
    }
    return this.token
  }

  public getUserDetails(): UserDetails {
    const token = this.getToken()
    let payload
    if (token) {
      payload = token.split('.')[1]
      payload = window.atob(payload)
      return JSON.parse(payload)
    } else {
      return null
    }
  }

  public isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    const user = this.getUserDetails()
    if (user) {
      return user.exp > Date.now() / 1000
    } else {
      return false
    }
  }

  public register(user: TokenPayload): Observable<any> {
    const base = this.http.post(`/users/register`, user)

    const request = base.pipe(
      map((data: TokenResponse) => {
        if (data.token) {
          this.saveToken(data.token)
        }
        return data
      })
    )

    return request
  }

  public login(user: TokenPayload): Observable<any> {
    const base = this.http.post(`/users/login`, user)

    const request = base.pipe(
      map((data: TokenResponse) => {
        if (data.token) {
          this.saveToken(data.token)
        }
        return data
      })
    )

    return request
  }

  public profile(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`/users/profile`, {
      headers: { Authorization: ` ${this.getToken()}` }
    })
  }

  public logout(): void {
    this.token = ''
    window.localStorage.removeItem('usertoken')
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the routes/Users.js Include this code

```
users.post('/register', async(req, res) => {
    try {
        const exists = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email})
        if(exists == null){
            res.statusCode = 200;
            res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
            res.json({success: true, status: 'You are allowed to register'});
        }else{
            res.statusCode=200;
            res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
            res.json({status: 'User already exists'});
        }
    }catch(error) {
        res.status(500).send({message: "Error checking"});
    }
})
```

Like I have done, If **email** of the user exists in the **User** schema of Database, then it will not allow you to register. You can use any other field also as you wish like firstname or lastname. 
Hope this helps.

You need to make changes like, make the user register instead of "you are allowed to register" in this code.

Comment: You can add this line like:-  var err=new Error("User exists"); console.log(err);

Comment: where I want to add this line..How to show this error on when I validate the login form and register form?

Comment: I hope the newly posted answer may solve your problem. Make use of postman, for testing these routes API endpoints, so that you can clearly give inputs and see response, and check whether data is storing the DB or not!

Answer (score 0):

```
    users.post('/register', async(req, res) => {
        try {
            const exists = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email})
            if(exists != null){
                res.statusCode = 200;
                res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
                var err = new Error();
                res.json({error: err, status: 'User already exists'});
            }
            else
            {
                const today = new Date()
                const userData = {
                        first_name: req.body.first_name,
                        last_name: req.body.last_name,
                        email: req.body.email,
                        password: req.body.password,
                        created: today
                    }
                User.create(userData)
                .then(user => {
                    const payload = {
                        _id: user._id,
                        first_name: user.first_name,
                        last_name: user.last_name,
                        email: user.email
                      }
                    let token = jwt.sign(payload, process.env.SECRET_KEY, {
                        expiresIn: 1440
                    })
                    res.json({ token: token })
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    res.send('error: ' + err)
                })
            }
        }catch(error) {
            res.status(500).send({message: "Error checking"});
        }
});
```

I have modified your code, Hope it works!:)

Comment: Getting this error   SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

Comment: oops! sorry, i forgot to add async to the (req,res) function. Now i have edited.

Comment: Not working .How to get that error message inside register() in register.component.ts